# Check if file exist, isn't empty and equal to another

Tags: files, scripting

I want to check if a file exist, isn't empty and equal to another file. If so, do nothing.

If they aren't equal then overwrite both files with `cat "some text"`.

If they don't exist or are empty then also create file with `cat some text`

I tried a few solutions, but whenever I get one condition right it makes another fail, or fail when no files exist.

What would be the cleanest way to solve this issue? All of this using bash?

Comment: While bash has some file test operators, it's not much of a text editor; did you mean that you were looking for a command-line-based solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if [ -f file1 ] && [ -s file1 ] && [ -f file2 ] && [ -s file2 ] &&
    cmp file1 file2 &>/dev/null; then
    : do nothing in this case only
else
    echo "some text" >file1
    echo "some text" >file2 # or cp file1 file2
fi
```

**and a shorter version, based on the comments**

```
if [ -s file1 ] && cmp file1 file2 &>/dev/null; then
    : do nothing in this case only
else
    echo "some text" >file1
    echo "some text" >file2 # or cp file1 file2
fi
```

Comment: lol you did what it took me ~40 lines to solve in just 7 lines. Thanks

Comment: I think we can drop the `&& [ -s file2 ]`, because if file2 would be empty at this point, the cmp would fail.

Comment: Also, if `[ -s something ]` is true, then `[ -f something ]` would be true as well, unless it's a non-regular file (but then `cmp` would fail).

Comment: @Kusalananda, `cmp` works on non-regular files as well. It's common to use it on fifos for instance (though here, you would probably want to abort with an error if either file was a fifo). There's also a potential problem with those approaches for files for which you have write but not read permission (in which case you could end up overwriting them even though they are identical). Unlikely in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a

```
if ! ( [[ -s file1 ]] && cmp file1 file2 2>/dev/null 1>&2 )
then
  echo "some text" >file1
  cp file1 file2
fi
```

Explanation:

-s file1 evaluates to true if file1 exists and is not empty.

The cmp command sets status code 0 if both files exist and are identical.

This is the case where we do not want to touch them, hence I prefix this by and exclamation mark, to negate the condition.

Comment: this would probably fail if file2 doesn't exist?

Comment: No, it works in this case too: If file2 does not exist, cmp writes an error message to stderr (which is not displayed due to redirection) and returns an exit code different from zero. This makes the `&&` expression false, the `if` becomes true, and the files are created.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `cmp -s` option:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! ( [[ -s file1 ]] && cmp -s file1 file2 )
then
    echo "some text" > file1
    cp file1 file2
fi
```

The `-s` option silently discards all output to `stdout` and `stderr` and just returns the exit status.

Comment: How, and *why*, does this differ from two previous answers?

Comment: @StephenRauch. Uses the `cmp -s` option instead of redirection to `/dev/null`

Comment: @StephenRauch.  I never claimed my answer was better.

Comment: @StephenRauch.   According to your definition, a good 50% of answers should not exist as they are similar to other existing answers.

Comment: OK, sorry I brought it up.